# trouble with Amazon s3 on plesk

Tags: amazon-s3, plesk-onyx

I am using plesk to back up to S3

I've configured the back up and it works on some sites but on others fails for no apparent reason.  The user permission scripts seem to be the same apart from the storage locations so this one works:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thechurch.org.uk",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thechurch.org.uk/*",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

but this one doesn't:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thechurchtwo.com",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thechurchtwo.com/*",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

plesk throws

Error: Error executing "CreateBucket" on "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/churchtwo"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/churchtwo` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:

`AccessDenied`Access DeniedXXXXXX (truncated...)
AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - 
`AccessDenied`Access DeniedXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I have made it work a few time but it seems to be luck.  Is there something about S3 that blocks a connection on a timeout or is my config wrong.

Any thoughts help would be great!

Comment: Are you using the same user account(/iAmRole)? Can you also add the command on plesk?

Comment: it's a different user.  Plesk is using a utility so I don't know the command but it's set up the same for both sites.  Is there something I should look for in the user settings?

Comment: so I've now figured out that it's a problem with Plesk not doing something correctly.  Once I hear back from them I'll add an update